# Migrate Logged Workflow Data to New Farm

Tags: workflow

I found out how to manually migrate the actual workflow, however, is there a way to migrate all the workflow history and task log as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. You can Migrate the workflow history, but the way it is laid out, it uses GUIDs for all the IDs of objects it references. I'm assuming that when you migrated the workflow to another site/web, that all the GUIDs changed, which will fail to reference the correct list/workflow/site, etc.

Comment: Hey Mike, yes all the GUIDs changed. Is there any workaround? I was thinking maybe using the list template with content and exporting it to the new farm and reconfiguring the workflow. Would that make any difference? I was hoping I could imoprt the list template then manually moving the workflow if the list template import keeps the history and log. Thanks!

Comment: So I did more reading and I know referencing a new GUIDs is possible, but will it show the data from the source workflow history? Thanks

Comment: You can re-reference the data after the fact with a powershell script that will replace one guid with another...